# JSDoc how to document array of arrays and boolean or other types for returns?

Tags: jsdoc

I have a function that returns a array like this: `[ [true, true], true]` where index 0 is an array of boolean and second a boolean. How can I document this in JSDoc return type.

I have tried: `@returns {[boolean[], boolean]}` which produces "unable to parse.."..."invalid type expression.." error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have complex type to return and perhaps [@typedef](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html) will be better option to set the type of return. But if you want to leave it as is, the following should work for you ...

```
@return {Array<Array<Boolean>, Boolean>}
```